# How to compare and replace rows in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have table 'key' with rows

```
happy new year
I love NY
```

I have table 'content' with rows

```
I want to say you: happy new year, Mike
I saw that banner with I love NY really
```

I would like to find in table 'content' words from table 'key' and replace it with hrefs. The table 'content' will be like

```
I want to say you: <a href="happy-new-year">happy new year</a>, Mike
I saw that banner with <a href="I-love-NY">I love NY</a> really
```

Is it possible to make it using mysql syntax?

Comment: is the rule replace spaces with dashes in the href ?

Comment: @amdixon yes, replace spaces with dashes in the href

Comment: do you need to check every row in content to replace with every row in key ?

Comment: @amdixon, I need to check every row in content and replace first match from key. I mean if in content i found row "hello, Bob and Rob" and in key table i found "Bob" row and "Rob" row after - I need to replace only Bob.  It will be: "hello, <a href="Bob"> and Rob"

Comment: it probably can be done with join, and using replace function, but I doubt if using sql query for this task is the right way. seems inefficient to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get pretty close with this:

```
update content c join
       keys k
       on c.col like concat('%', k.col, '%')
    set c.col = replace(c.col, k.col,
                        concat('<a href="', replace(k.col, ' ', '-'), '">',
                               k.col, '</a>')
                       );
```

The way that `update` works with multiple matches is that only *one* of the matches takes effect.  So, this will only replace one key value.  But, it will do it throughout the entire string.  In other words, if the same key appears multiple times, then it will be replaced each time.